# How to pull Csv Import Task Response File from NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I need to pull a CSV response file generated from a Csv import task.

Looking at the UI, the URL for the response files is

```
https://<accountId>.app.netsuite.com/app/setup/upload/csv/uploadlogcsv.nl?wqid=<wqid>
```

Unfortunately the `wqid` does not match the `taskId` generated via the `SuiteScript` `task.Submit()` method. How can I obtain a `wqid` for a given `taskId`?

I don't see a mention of pulling the response file via `SuiteScript` in the documentation.

Is there a way to programmatically pull a Csv response file for a programmatically triggered Csv Import Task?